# Oscommerce display default product image and prevent it from deletion

Tags: image, set, default, product, oscommerce

I am working on an oscommerce project where i want to display default product image (i.e no image available) if product image is not uploaded.And even i want it to prevent from deletion.I have tried to upload product not available image for 2-3 products but when deleting products i.e final last product image also gets deleted from the folder.I want that if user doesn't upload image then by default no_product_available.jpg should be shown in CATEGORIES.php as well as PRODUCT_INFO.php.

Can anyone help me to do this ? I am using oscommerce default template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you would like to do... Pretty much you're saying that if someone doesn't upload an image with a product or category then you would like the no_image.jpg image to be displayed instead of nothing being displayed.  Additionally, you would like for the no_image.jpg to not be deleted if the category or product is deleted.  I think I can help with this...

You need to modify the tep_image() function located in catalog/includes/function/html_output.php

Replace...

```
if ( (empty($src) || ($src == DIR_WS_IMAGES)) && (IMAGE_REQUIRED == 'false') ) {
  return false;
}
```

With...

```
if (!is_file($src)) {
$src = "images/no_image.jpg";
}
```

Now when you use the tep_image() function if no image was uploaded or if the file is specified but missing from the server then no_image.jpg will be displayed.  When the category or product is deleted the is no_image.jpg file is not associated with the category or product so nothing is deleted.  Obviously, replace "images/no_image.jpg" with the correct location and filename for your default no image file.  Also, you may wish to modify the code above to get the specific behavior you want but this is a good starting point to achieve what you want.

The index.php and product_info.php pages use tep_image()... So, you should be all set there.  If you're making your own page or modifying an existing one then you would of course need to use the tep_image() function to get the no_image.jpg output functionality.  The parameters for tep_image() are...

```
tep_image($src, $alt = '', $width = '', $height = '', $parameters = '')
```

UPDATE:
tep_image should already be in both the index.php (the page that generates the category/product list pages) and product_info.php.  Just open either file and search for "tep_image" without quotes or parentheses.  You should find several instances in both files.  Examine the code to understand what has already been done so that when you add a new image you understand the correct syntax.

Pretty much just place tep_image where you want your new image to show up on the page.  You need to be familiar with HTML and PHP to read through the page and determine where you want the image placed.  If you want to move the current image then you might be able to just cut and paste the current tep_image code to a your new location.

You can also use "Inspect Element" in Chrome in the right click menu to help determine location.  Just open the page you want to add an image to and right click in the area you want to add an image to.  Then look at the surrounding page source code.  Now you have an idea what to look for in the PHP file.

BTW, the index.php page is a little tricky.  That page is responsible for the homepage, category listing pages, and product listing pages.  Also, there are several other module PHP pages that are Included (so the source code is in a different file that you'll need to track down if that's the area you want to add the image to).  Make sense ;-)

Give it a try and write back with what want specifically and you did to achieve it.  There are lots of people that have helped me in the past.  So, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Can you please help me to place tep_image function in products_info and categories page.I am using oscommerce default template.And I M TOTALLY Newbie to Oscommerce. Help really appreciated